# Cannot compile stm32l4r5xx while using malloc/new

Tags: c++, c, malloc, microcontroller, stm32

I met a strange problem. I use Eclipse Oxygen.2, windows 10, J-linker, STM32L4R5ZI, STM32CubeMX V1.0 ver 4.26.0.

The problem:
I can compile my programs and run them on the uC, but whenever I want to use the 'malloc' or 'new' functions I cannot compile my project and receive the following message:

```
../system/src/newlib/_sbrk.c:84: undefined reference to `_Heap_Begin'
../system/src/newlib/_sbrk.c:84: undefined reference to `_Heap_Limit'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

The main function:

```
int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  uint8_t *tab = malloc(100);    

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();      
  HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);      
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7);

  while (1)
  {    
  }    
}
```

The _sbrk.c:

```
_sbrk(int incr)
{
  extern char _Heap_Begin; // Defined by the linker.
  extern char _Heap_Limit; // Defined by the linker.

  static char* current_heap_end;
  char* current_block_address;

  if (current_heap_end == 0)
    {
      current_heap_end = &_Heap_Begin;
    }

  current_block_address = current_heap_end;

  // Need to align heap to word boundary, else will get
  // hard faults on Cortex-M0. So we assume that heap starts on
  // word boundary, hence make sure we always add a multiple of
  // 4 to it.
  incr = (incr + 3) & (~3); // align value to 4
  if (current_heap_end + incr > &_Heap_Limit)
    {
      // Some of the libstdc++-v3 tests rely upon detecting
      // out of memory errors, so do not abort here.
#if 0
      extern void abort (void);

      _write (1, "_sbrk: Heap and stack collision\n", 32);

      abort ();
#else
      // Heap has overflowed
      errno = ENOMEM;
      return (caddr_t) - 1;
#endif
    }

  current_heap_end += incr;

  return (caddr_t) current_block_address;
}
```

Comment: I am not using your plattform but the error is a linking error.  `extern char _Heap_Begin;` is a symbole which is generated by the linker. So you should search if you can find an option to enable the heap. Maybe you have to edit the linker file.

Comment: There should be no reason why you need to use dynamic memory allocation on a Cortex M. It is not a PC.

Comment: @gotocoffe thank you for your answerd. I cannot find any option like that in Eclipse. However the definition was found in another file as was posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_Heap_Begin` and `_Heap_Limit` are values coming from the linker. These should be defined in the linker scripts you use. Typically in the projects created by CubeMX those are located in the `sections.ld` like so:

```
PROVIDE ( _Heap_Begin = _end_noinit ) ;
PROVIDE ( _Heap_Limit = __stack - __Main_Stack_Size ) ;
```

Check whether those definitions are there and if you use those files during linking - you should see them passed as command line arguments, e.g.

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 [...] -T "path/to/sections.ld" [...]
```

This is controlled by going to project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings tab -> Cross ARM C++ Linker -> General -> Script Files (-T).

Comment: Thank you for your answere. Once I added the sections.ld file to the linker I can compile the project. However, the uC stacks on the malloc line and goes to the endless loop.
While building the solution I get as follows:
sections.ld:259: warning: memory region `CCMRAM' not declared
366: warning: memory region `FLASHB1' not declared
374: warning: memory region `EXTMEMB0' not declared
382: warning: memory region `EXTMEMB1' not declared
90: warning: memory region `EXTMEMB2' not declared
411: warning: memory region `EXTMEMB3' not declared

Comment: Those regions are declared in `mem.ld`. Overall CubeMX generates a project with 3 linker script files: `mem.ld`, `libs.ld` and `sections.ld`. You should use all of them in your project.

Comment: Thank you. that solved the problem with compiling.
What about landing in endless loop while execulting malloc?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. Maybe incorrect definition of heap location (malloc attempting to use memory that is not in the address space of the MCU)? It's hard to tell withoud debugging.